# How to use rownum in Hibernate for greater or less?

Tags: hibernate

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
WHERE PARATYPE = 'A'
AND MODELID = '50'
AND 'BA1' BETWEEN RAWMIN AND RAWMAX
AND ROWNUM < 2 ;
```

I have the above query. I have difficulty in converting rownum < 2 in plsql to Hibernate query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for '<' we use < in hql